# JavaScript loop won't separate <TD> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, jsonp

I am using JavaScript to fetch some XML data and loop it in a table. However the TD elements won't separate to a new line.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="gData">
    <table class="tftable" border="1">
        <tr><th>Date</th><th>Game</th><th>Home</th><th>Draw</th><th>Away</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="gDate"></td>
            <td class="gGame"></td>
            <td class="gHome"></td>
            <td class="gDraw"></td>
            <td class="gAway"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is my JS:

```
window['gCallback'] = function(data) {

    var game_data = data.query.results.rsp.fd.sports.sport.leagues.league.events.event; 

    for (var i = 0; i < game_data.length; i++) { 

        $('#gData .gGame').append( '<td>' + game_data[i].homeTeam.name + ' vs ' + game_data[i].awayTeam.name + '</td>   '); 
        $('#gData .gDate').append( '<td>' + game_data[i].startDateTime) + '</td>';  
        $('#gData .gAway').append( '<td>' + game_data[i].periods.period[i].moneyLine.awayPrice) + '</td>';
        $('#gData .gHome').append( '<td>' + game_data[i].periods.period[i].moneyLine.homePrice) + '</td>';
        $('#gData .gDraw').append( '<td>' + game_data[i].periods.period[i].moneyLine.drawPrice) + '</td>';

      }
};
```

The data comes back fine from the loop but displays all the dates in one TD, all the Games in the next TD.

Comment: What are you doing? Because I don't think you're doing what you think you're doing...

Comment: Less cryptically, why do you think appending a `<td>` to something that is already a `<td>` is a good idea?

Comment: Looks like you want to render a TR for each set of TDs?

Comment: Ya, TDs are cells, TRs are rows

Comment: I know the above questions generates a td inside of a td.  The dates for example gets repeated <td class="gDate">**HERE**</td>  I need a way of making a new row for each loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also create your `tr` tags dynamically. Here's what I would suggest:

First make sure your table has a `thead` and `tbody`.

```
<table id="my-table">
    <thead>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Game</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Draw</th>
        <th>Away</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
<table>
```

Then you can generate your rows dynamically and append them to the `tbody` element. To save on writing i'll just give an example that isin't based on your code.

```
var $trs = $(document.createDocumentFragment()), //reduce DOM reflows
    data = [{ a:1, b:2, c:3 }],
    i = 0,
    len = data.length,
    rowData, $tr;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    rowData = data[i];

    $tr = $('<tr>'); //create your row

    //append cells, you can also create a function to encapsulate
    //that repetitive logic
    $tr.append($('<td>').addClass('yourClass').text(rowData.a));
    $tr.append($('<td>').addClass('yourOtherClass').text(rowData.b));
    $tr.append($('<td>').addClass('yetAnotherClass').text(rowData.c));

    //append the tr to the document fragment
    $trs.append($tr);

}

//append the document fragment to the tbody
$('#my-table > tbody').append($trs);
```

Comment: @plalx Nice answer, but seeing how the data is already dynamically generated, why can't I cant generate a tr class around the data?  ' $('#gData .gDate').append( '<td>' + game_data[i].startDateTime) + '</td>'; ' for example?

Comment: @ServerSideSkittles Not sure to understand what you mean by "the data is already dynamically generated". The issue with your code sample is that `.gDate` is a cell and youre's adding another cell into it. Actually multiple cells since you are looping. If you have **multiple** rows with all cells generated already and you want to put data into cells, you could do `$('#gData .gDate:eq(' + i + ')').text(game_data[i].startDateTime);` but that would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

It's remarkable how even the simplest task can be butchered by jQuery...

```js
var table = document.getElementById('gData').children[0],
    tbody = table.tBodies[0];
window['gCallback'] = function(data) {
    var game_data = data.query.results.rsp.fd.sprts.sport.leages.leage.events.event,
        len = game_data.length, i, tr;
    table.removeChild(tbody);
    for( i=0; i<len; i++) {
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(game_data[i].homeTeam.name));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(game_data[i].startDateTime));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(game_data[i].periods.period[i].moneyLine.awayPrice));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(game_data[i].periods.period[i].moneyLine.homePrice));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                  .appendChild(document.createTextNode(game_data[i].periods.period[i].moneyLine.drawPrice));
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    table.appendChild(tbody);
};
```

And this HTML:

```
<div id="gData">
    <table class="tftable" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Date</th><th>Game</th><th>Home</th><th>Draw</th><th>Away</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Note that you can simplify the above code with a helper function:

```
function addCellWithText(tr,text) {
    return tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}
```

Then your loop's contents become:

```
for(...) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    addCellWithText(tr,game_data[i].homeTeam.name);
    addCellWithText(tr,game_data[i].startDateTime);
    addCellWithText(tr,game_data[i].preiods.period[i].moneyLine.homePrice);
    addCellWithText(tr,game_data[i].preiods.period[i].moneyLine.awayPrice);
    addCellWithText(tr,game_data[i].preiods.period[i].moneyLine.drawPrice);
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: "butchered by jQuery" ??? This is typical case where jQuery could be used to make code a little more consistent and readable IMHO

Comment: It could be, sure, but sadly jQuery is a tool given to far too many people... Honestly, jQuery should not be free, it just invites trouble.

Comment: I think problem is people using jQuery without knowing javascript

Comment: If you used jQuery you could save a lot of typing!

Comment: Anyway +1 for the 'pure JS' way of doing it  ;)

Comment: @geedubb Or you could make a helper function to do the specific task you want to do, as I demonstrated.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I agree jQuery is often over-used, however it's far more important to reduce DOM manipulations than avoiding jQuery's syntaxic sugar. See my answer.

Comment: @plalx Your code has MORE DOM manipulations than mine! Just because you yourself have written less code, doesn't mean that less code is being run! jQuery is bloatware, put simply, and it should not be used for any serious application.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It was implicit that by DOM manipulation I meant manipulating the document's DOM. Manipulating in-memory DOM elements using jQuery shouldn't have any noticeable performance impact, unless there's a lot of rows. Your solution will run slower than mine, just because you are causing multiple DOM reflows, which are worst than anything else.

Comment: Oh yeah, how about now? :p Now mine's guaranteed faster because [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is just that awesome :3

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Hahaha, I like that site man! =) Never seen it before, so funny. I likke Vanilla JS too, but when it doesn't hurt cross-browser compatibility. You surely wouldn't want to write vanilla  ajax calls and deal with old browsers. Hopefully now everthing is more standardized. Anyway, Dart saves us all =P

Comment: AJAX has been standardised for YEARS now. It's only IE6 that doesn't support it, and nobody should support such an ancient browser any more.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Well I'm forced to work with IE 8 at work and it doesn't support `XMLHttpRequest` either. Anyway, I still wouldn't want to deal with HTTP status codes most of the time. Using promises/deferreds/futures is quite more elegant as well. Frameworks aren't evil (well some of them are), but people using them often are. Do you really think that Google uses vanilla JS for everything they do?

Comment: Er... yes it does. Even IE7 supports `XMLHttpRequest`. I don't object to frameworks, but I personally prefer to build my own. Therefore, I have a `window.ajax` function that handles all my AJAX needs. I could add browser compatibility to it, if I could be arsed. But honestly, if users go out of their way to disable Windows Update and instead continue using obsolete browsers, why should I spend time, effort and money getting things to work for them?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah you are right, it seems it does. It must be the way it's configured for the intranet then. I never really bothered. Writing your own framework is a good way to learn and could even sometimes be required if nothing out there suits your needs, but why reinventing the wheel? Have you ever looked at Google's AngularJS framework? That's a masterpiece and HTML's heading in that direction anyway with [Web Components](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/explainer/).

Comment: I write my own frameworks as a kind of psyche thing. People blame their tools first. If I were to use jQuery (or any framework) and things break, then I would accuse the framework of being wrong. However, if *I wrote it*, then I can only blame myself and will immediately fix it. On top of that, using my own framework allows me to make safe assumptions, like "AJAX responses will always be JSON", "said JSON responses will always have an "ok" property and, in case of failure, an "error" property", and even "if there's an error, it looks like this and can be extrated to show as a proper message".